# multi font textview in android

Tags: android, fonts, textview, custom-font

i have create [customFontTextView](http://goo.gl/x17m1m) in android but is it possible to have my `customFontTextView` support all regional language.All font file will given in assets folder

i am able to change font in my `customFontTextView` for different font in XML i.e if i have set `Arial.ttf` than it show Arial font when i change font in XML some hindifont than is show hindi, i need to change every time in XML so any trick to change font of textview runtime as language change

scenario like

```
CustomTextView tvTitle = (CustomTextView).findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
tvTitle.setText("English Font");
tvTitle.setText("ગુજરાતી ફોન્ટ");
tvTitle.setText("हिन्दी फॉन्ट");
tvTitle.setText("same as other language font");
```

Note:in some device regional fonts are not supported like MOTO G,E,X  so i need this

Comment: @Paul have understand my question ?? its not duplicate they are talking about style and i am talking about font

Comment: Well, you want to have multiple fonts in the same textview, right? Like 'Engilsh font' would be in a normal font, and that second words in a font that supports that language.

Comment: ya my TextView should support all regional language,  is it possible ?? i have search for it but not get any thing so i have ask here :)

Answer (score 0):

If i don't misunderstood your question, you want to set a Font (ex:Helvetica for english, Arial for Hindi, and so on....) on your textView.

Well you can do a if on start to get the locale of the device, if hindi get the font Arial and set this to your textview, else get the Helvetica.

```
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Helvetica.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

You can do the "if" with Locale.getDefaultLocale and Locale.forLanguageTag(languageTag)

Note: I simplified the example with Arial and Helvetica, but i know you are talking about multilanguage fonts, just change the fonts.

It's helps?